# Where is the latest Sonatype Nexus OSS REST API?

Tags: api, nexus, sonatype

I always use this page: http://nexus.xwiki.org/nexus/nexus-core-documentation-plugin/core/docs/index.html, but its sub-page could not open now(404 - Not Found). 
Who knows where the latest API page is located?

Comment: You accepted an answer that is wrong. Please have a look at the correct answer so we do not misguide other users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The REST API is still part of Nexus of course. Since the API sometimes changes, you should look it up within your own Nexus instance and version! You can find it in the Plugin Console with the Restlet 1x Plugin.

More details are here: http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-plugins.html

If you want to have a local copy and e.g. your admin does not give you access, you can just start up a fresh install of Nexus on your machine locally. You will be admin on that fresh install and be able to see the docs. Also keep in mind you pretty much need the REST API only if you are developing some sort of integration. If you are doing that you should test against a local Nexus instance anyway... so you will have the docs right there.

Also if you know the entry point to the docs you can access them directly. E.g.
https://oss.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/index.html

Comment: you need to be admin to see the plugin console. why don't you just post the link?

Comment: You do not need to be admin. Your admin just needs to give normal users access to the Plugin Console. There is no hosted Nexus I am aware of that has it publicly available. I will see if can change that. I also updated the answer with another idea.

Comment: Restlet 1.x API is not humanity. For example I want get repo_group information, and I can use "http://ip:port/nexus/service/local/repo_groups". Restlet 1.x API could not use search, there are too many resources, ctrl+F could not find "repo_groups". I have to read each resources to find the api, it wasted my time. English is not my mother language, I had to use search to find the same word, so, in my opinion Restlet 1.x API is too hard to use, and it could not be the right answer for some people who don't good at English.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point. You might not like the API, but  that is an entirely different aspect. I am just pointing out where to find the docs. Also Nexus is open source so feel free to submit improvements for the documentation.

Comment: You are right. This is the right answer, that one is the best answer for those people who is not good at english.

Answer (score 2):

seems to have disappeared...

Newer Nexus releases include this documentation though (at least 2.0.4-1 does). Substitute nexus.xwiki.org with another hostname, e.g. the hostname of your company's nexus server (you might have to drop the /nexus part):

http://[your-own-nexus]/nexus/nexus-core-documentation-plugin/core/docs/index.html

[**EDIT**]

found the API doc on a publicly available instance of Nexus 2.1 [here](https://maven.java.net/nexus-core-documentation-plugin/core/docs/rest.artifact.maven.redirect.html)

Comment: Nexus 2.3.x doesn't include the doc."Nexus 2.1 here" is OK!